# Output format when sending the mail using mailx

Tags: linux, bash

I have a summary file which needs to be displayed with formatting as it is in the OS to the mail.

Summary.txt

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Total files deleted: 55

@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Total Files fixed :77
Path :/tmp
```

But when mail is sent the formatting is lost ( i even tried cat -e)

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Total files deleted: 55 @@@@@@@@@@@@@ Total Files fixed :77 Path :/tmp
```

Following is the code, can anyone help me to preserve the formatting

```
summary=`cat /tmp/Summary.txt`
body="Hi Team, \n\n Find below  summary . \n\n $summary \n\nRegards"
echo -e $body | mail -s "$SID: Job Report" -a $asummary -a $tsummary $mail
```

Comment: Quote your variables, i.e. `echo -e "$body" | ...` and remove the space characters before and after `\n\n`.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
summary=`cat /tmp/Summary.txt`
echo -e "Hi Team,\n\nFind below summary .\n\n${summary}\n\nRegards" | \
mail -s "$SID:Job Report" -a $asummary -a $tsummary $mail
```

note: you can split a shell command over multiple lines by using `\`

Comment: How does this differ from what's in the question, except that you don't have that `body` variable?

Comment: he can directly do `echo -e "${body}"` and removing spaces before and after `\n` and everything will be okay, but there's no need to declare a new variable for that reason, I prefer to make everything sample as much as I can.